# SQL IF EXIST UPDATE ELSE INSERT prepared statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I'm breaking my brains over this, i would realy appriciate help!

This is the code i have so far..

```
$conn = db_connect();                       
$sql = "INSERT INTO measurements
(`date`, `weight`, `waist`, `id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn-> prepare($sql); 
$stmt ->bind_param("sddi", $date, $_POST['weight'], $_POST['waist'], $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Its a prepared statement for an sql insert. Now i want to change it to a IF EXIST THEN UPDATE ELSE insert the way i am doing right now. something like this but then with a prepared statement:

```
IF EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE user_id=’4’)
UPDATE measurements SET (`weight`=40, `waist`=45) WHERE user_id=’4’
ELSE
INSERT INTO measurements 
VALUES (`date`='week 1', `weight`= 40, `waist`=45, `id`=4)
```

I found some articles on stackoverflow about the if EXIST then update else insert but i did not find it with a prepared statement in it that worked for me.

Thanks a thousand!

UPDATE:

i've changed it to dublicate key style.

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO measurements (uniqueID, date, weight, waist) 
VALUES ('$uniqueID', '$date', '$weight',  '$waist') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight= '$weight', waist= '$waist'";

$conn->query($sql);
```

Now the second part of the question, how do i make this a prepared statement?

Answer (score 2):

To implement Mr. Jones' solution as a `mysqli` prepared statement, you would code it thus:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO measurements
            (`uniqueID`, `date`, weight, waist) 
          VALUES
            (?, ?, ?, ?) 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY
            UPDATE weight = ?, waist = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt ->bind_param("isdddd", $user_id, $date, $_POST['weight'], $_POST['waist'], $_POST['weight'], $_POST['waist']);
$stmt->execute();
```

A slightly cleaner implementation would be to use `PDO`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO measurements
            (`uniqueID`, `date`, weight, waist) 
          VALUES
            (:uniqueId, :date, :weight, :waist) 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY
            UPDATE weight = :weight, waist = :waist";
/* $conn is a PDO object */
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':uniqueId' => $user_id, ':date' => $date, ':weight' => $_POST['weight'], ':waist' => $_POST['waist']));
```

Note that with named placeholders, you can use the same name in more than one place and only need to assign the value once.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, both codes do not seem to work properly. the first code does not implement the rows. and the second code the PDO version gives me this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /www/appPHP.php
 on line 232

Comment: and when i remove the '' around my $variables like in your example i get:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in www/appPHP.php on line
 233

Comment: @Samvanbeastlo Of course, `date` is a reserved word so it must be escaped with backticks to be used as a column name. Sorry about that.

Comment: Even with the changes i still get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in www/appPHP.php
 on line 232. there is something wrong with the execute

Comment: @Samvanbeastlo No, that means that the `prepare` is failing. For the PDO version of the code, you are using a PDO connection and not a mysqli connection, right?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's approach to this is `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. It works well; in particular it avoids race conditions if more than one database connection tries to hit the same row.

This requires the table that's the target of your UPSERT to have a meaningful unique index or primary key. It looks like your `id` is that key.

You can absolutely use parameter binding to present data to this.

You can read about it here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've changed the code and updated it, but the article didn't say how to make it a prepared statement. Can you help me with that so that i can check your awnser. I've updated my question with the code i have right now. Thanks alot!