# Control data if exist in array

Tags: php, mysql

i have two different table in mysql and i am getting data from a json file with curl.

My first table name is "tblclients" which is this table store client data. My second table name is "tblcustomfieldsvalues" and this table using "tblclients" table's "id" value for "$relid" column. (id value is primary key and autoincrement for "tblclients")

When i am getting data from json file i can check "value" column from "tblcustomfieldsvalues" because this is only one unique value in the json file.

So, i want to check my mysql table if i have same data comes from the json file.
If yes, i need to update data. If not, i have to insert new data.

And also, i want to do same progress for my "tblclients" data. But this one is really confused me because i don't know how to i check same data if is exist.

I think i should do some sql query for it. But i couldn't figure that out.

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
curl_close($curl);
//print_r($result);
//print_r($json);

$inserted_rows = 0;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(" INSERT INTO tblclients(company,country,active,datecreated,default_currency,show_primary_contact,registration_confirmed,addedfrom,phonenumber) 
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("siisiiiis", $company, $country, $active, $datecreated, $default_currency, $show_primary_contact, $registration_confirmed, $addedfrom, $phonenumber);

$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare(" INSERT INTO tblcustomfieldsvalues(relid,fieldid,fieldto,value) 
VALUES(?,?,?,?)");


$stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare(" INSERT INTO tblcontacts(userid, is_primary, firstname, lastname, datecreated, email, phonenumber) 
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");


$stmt2->bind_param("iiss", $relid, $fieldid, $fieldto, $customercode);

$stmt3->bind_param("iisssss", $userid, $is_primary, $firstname, $lastname, $datecreated2, $email, $phonenumber);

foreach ($json['result'] as $product) {


    $company = $product['company'];
    $country = $product['country'];
    $active = $product['active'];
    $datecreated = $product['_date'];
    $default_currency = $product['crr'];
    $show_primary_contact = $product['contact'];
    $registration_confirmed = $product['confirmed'];
    $addedfrom = $product['from'];

    $stmt->execute();

    $relid = $stmt->insert_id;
    $fieldid = "1";
    $fieldto = "customers";
    $customercode = $product['customercode'];

    $stmt2->execute();


    $userid = $stmt->insert_id;
    $is_primary = "1";
    $firstname = $product['related'];

    if ($email === NULL) {
        $email = " ";
    } else {
        $email = $product['email'];
    }

    $phonenumber = $product['phone'];

    $lastname = " ";
    $datecreated2 = $product['_dates'];

    $stmt3->execute();

    $inserted_rows++;
}


?>
```

also sql file (related tables) below;

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Oct 18, 2022 at 11:21 AM
-- Server version: 10.4.21-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 8.1.1

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `test`

-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `tblclients`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblclients` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phonenumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datecreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `leadid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_street` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_zip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_country` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `shipping_street` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_zip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_country` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `longitude` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_language` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_currency` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `show_primary_contact` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `stripe_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registration_confirmed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `addedfrom` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblclients`
--

INSERT INTO `tblclients` (`userid`, `company`, `vat`, `phonenumber`, `country`, `city`, `zip`, `state`, `address`, `website`, `datecreated`, `active`, `leadid`, `billing_street`, `billing_city`, `billing_state`, `billing_zip`, `billing_country`, `shipping_street`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_state`, `shipping_zip`, `shipping_country`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `default_language`, `default_currency`, `show_primary_contact`, `stripe_id`, `registration_confirmed`, `addedfrom`) VALUES
(1, 'TEST COMPANY', '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '2022-10-18 12:19:49', 1, NULL, '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', 0, NULL, NULL, '', 0, 0, NULL, 1, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblcontacts`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblcontacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_primary` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `firstname` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phonenumber` text NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datecreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_pass_key` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_pass_key_requested` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_verification_key` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_verification_sent_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_ip` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_password_change` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `profile_image` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direction` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `estimate_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `credit_note_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `contract_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `task_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `project_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `ticket_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblcontacts`
--

INSERT INTO `tblcontacts` (`id`, `userid`, `is_primary`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `phonenumber`, `title`, `datecreated`, `password`, `new_pass_key`, `new_pass_key_requested`, `email_verified_at`, `email_verification_key`, `email_verification_sent_at`, `last_ip`, `last_login`, `last_password_change`, `active`, `profile_image`, `direction`, `invoice_emails`, `estimate_emails`, `credit_note_emails`, `contract_emails`, `task_emails`, `project_emails`, `ticket_emails`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'TEST NAME', 'TEST LASTNAME', 'TEST@MAIL.COM', '', '', '2022-10-18 12:20:13', '$2a$08$sFmYWS6beMwnSlr90MvSwOOEFy0LIbUJ5iPePHpnN/Y0I/QWCImdO', NULL, NULL, '2022-10-18 12:20:13', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, '', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblcustomfieldsvalues`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblcustomfieldsvalues` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldto` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblcustomfieldsvalues`
--

INSERT INTO `tblcustomfieldsvalues` (`id`, `relid`, `fieldid`, `fieldto`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'customers', 'TEST CUSTOMER CODE');

-- --------------------------------------------------------


-- Indexes for table `tblclients`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblclients`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userid`);

--

--
-- Indexes for table `tblcustomfieldsvalues`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblcustomfieldsvalues`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `relid` (`relid`),
  ADD KEY `fieldto` (`fieldto`),
  ADD KEY `fieldid` (`fieldid`);


--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblclients`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblclients`
  MODIFY `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--

-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblcustomfieldsvalues`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblcustomfieldsvalues`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--


/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And i am new for coding, if you see any mistake or something please let me know and i can learn more.

Comment: `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I couldn't figure that out how to do with an array. Could you please help me with my code?

Comment: I don't think you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for this. If the row already exists, you need to use a `SELECT` query to get its ID, otherwise you use `$stmt->insert_id` to get the ID of the new row. @Nbk

Comment: Is `$userid` supposed to be the same `$stmt->insert_id` as `$relid`? Or should that be `$stmt2->insert_id`?

Comment: Yes it supposed to be same. $userid does same thing with $relid. I am adding data tblcustomfieldsvalues table and tblcontacts table according to tblclients id

Comment: the user said, *if the row already exists*, so he **must** have a possibility to detect it, and so he can use a unique or primary key for the duplicate detection, and a scalar value like user_id can be optained in a `ON DUPLICATE`, if that is not in the INSERT Statement, which not makes an sense as the value **must** be optained before the databse can enter it. Afte ral consoderations my first coment, seems to be for that scnario one solution

Comment: **if i have same data comes from the json file. If yes, i need to update data. If not, i have to insert new data.** - please first define what is the meaning of "same data" .  (Say: which one of the following fields is the primary key / unique key? : company,country,active,datecreated,default_currency,show_primary_contact,registration_confirmed,addedfrom,phonenumber)

Comment: Hello, @KenLee thank you for your helps again. 

You were modified my codes previous days. We were add tblclients "id" to tblcustomfieldsvalues "relid" column for each new row. And it s works fine.

I have added my mysql related tables to my first post. Please check codes. 

tblclients table doesnt have any unique row. But tblcustomfieldsvalues does. This is "value" column and i am using this area for keep customer codes.  

So may be we can check transfer during adding row tblcustomfieldsvalues? 

So i am not sure can we control tblclients table if there is same row.

Comment: @KenLee  I did something like this but it's still adding row. Where is my fault? $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare
(" INSERT INTO tblcustomfieldsvalues(relid,fieldid,fieldto,value) 
VALUES(?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE relid = VALUES(relid),fieldid = VALUES(fieldid),fieldto = VALUES(fieldto),value = VALUES(value), id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i figured out. I put this code

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare (" INSERT INTO tblcustomfieldsvalues(relid,fieldid,fieldto,value) VALUES(?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE relid = VALUES(relid),fieldid = VALUES(fieldid),fieldto = VALUES(fieldto),value = VALUES(value), id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)");
```

and i set unique "value" column at the table. Everything is ok now.

Comment: great ! have a good day